# Logic rules of Python's `if` clause

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements

I have an `if` condition in my code which seems for example like this:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = [7,8,9]
```

I want `'If'` to return **true** when (**1** is in **a**) or (**1** is in **b**) or (**1** is in **c**) or (**5** is in **a**) or (**5** is in **b**) or (**5** is in **c**)

I've tried:

```
if (1 or 5) in (a or b or c):
    pass
```

But this obviously didn't work that way.
Could you give me a hint? Thanks

Comment: `(1 or 5)` is evaluated to 1, since it's True and `int(True)` is 1.

Comment: And `(a or b or c)` evaluates to `a` since that is non-empty. Together you essentially have `1 in a`.

Comment: try `if 1 in a or 4 in b:` something like this. you can get better better for this. so just explore a little.

Comment: You almost had it: `if (1 in a) or (1 in b) or (1 in c) or (5 in a) or (5 in b) or (5 in c):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for me, though there might be a built in to concatenate the three lists.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = [7,8,9]  
target = [1,5]

any(x for x in (a+b+c) if x in target)

True
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use sets:

```
a = {1, 2, 3}
b = {4, 5, 6}
c = {7, 8, 9}

a | b | c
#>>> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

{1, 5} & (a | b | c)
#>>> {1, 5}

bool({1, 5} & (a | b | c))
#>>> True

if {1, 5} & (a | b | c):
    print("Yeah!")
#>>> Yeah!

if not {1, 5}.isdisjoint(a | b | c):
    print("Yeah!")    
#>>> Yeah!
```

If you want short-circuiting:

```
if not all({1, 5}.isdisjoint(items) for items in (a, b, c)):
    print("Yeah!")    
#>>> Yeah!
```